# Ibatis 2.3 : ProbeException : There is no READABLE property

Tags: java, mybatis, ibatis

Using Ibatis 2.3.1.710, i'm getting the following Exception  :

```
com.ibatis.common.beans.ProbeException: There is no READABLE property named 'newDate' in class 'com.myProject.common.vo.MyObject'
            at com.ibatis.common.beans.ClassInfo.getGetterType(ClassInfo.java:431)
            at com.ibatis.common.beans.GenericProbe.getClassPropertyTypeForGetter(GenericProbe.java:224)
            at com.ibatis.common.beans.GenericProbe.getPropertyTypeForGetter(GenericProbe.java:153)
            at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.parameter.InlineParameterMapParser.resolveTypeHandler(InlineParameterMapParser.java:229)
            at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.parameter.InlineParameterMapParser.oldParseMapping(InlineParameterMapParser.java:161)
            at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.parameter.InlineParameterMapParser.parseInlineParameterMap(InlineParameterMapParser.java:48)
            at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.config.MappedStatementConfig.applyInlineParameterMap(MappedStatementConfig.java:189)
            at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.config.MappedStatementConfig.setSqlForStatement(MappedStatementConfig.java:173)
            at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.config.MappedStatementConfig.<init>(MappedStatementConfig.java:80)
            at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.config.SqlMapConfiguration.newMappedStatementConfig(SqlMapConfiguration.java:159)
            at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.builder.xml.SqlStatementParser.parseGeneralStatement(SqlStatementParser.java:73)
            at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.builder.xml.SqlMapParser$18.process(SqlMapParser.java:346)
            at com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletParser.processNodelet(NodeletParser.java:
```

Trying to find out what's the cause, I noticed that i slightly modified my entity class by making the setter return the object instead of void, Can that provoke that stacktrace and if so, why ? :

```
public Date getNewDate() {
    return newDate;
}


public MyObject setNewDate(Date newDate) {
    this.newDate = newDate;
    return this;
}
```

Comment: As `ClassInfo` is a standalone utility, it's easy to test `ClassInfo.getInstance(MyObject.class).getGetterType("newDate")`. It returned `java.util.Date` for a bean with those methods, so there may be something else interfering the getter detection. The source is [here](https://archive.apache.org/dist/ibatis/binaries/ibatis.java/).

Comment: Thank Ave for your answer and your help, could it be the fact that in the resultMap for that class, in sqlmap file, does not contain that property ? But then again, it used to work without it..

Comment: I don't think resultMap matters. The one-liner in my previous comment reproduced the error, right?  
You should create a bean that has only `newDate` and keep copying fields/methods from `MyObject` until the error reproduces.  
If you could post the complete `MyObject` including superclasses/interfaces, I would look into it when I have some spare time.